# Xamarin.Forms iOs project FileNotFoundException on Host invalid path

Tags: xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, filenotfoundexception

I develop a cross-platform app using Visual Studio 2015 and build iOS app using an host.
The build failed with this exception :

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TeedlMobileiOS/44a299393b33183ffe81e6e2cebbc7ad/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Images/Calendar/datecell.png does not exist`

When I check on my mac, I see that this image is called "Images\Calendar\datecell.png" and its path is "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TeedlMobileiOS/44a299393b33183ffe81e6e2cebbc7ad/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Images\Calendar\datecell.png"

The path is not correctly set and it's the same issue for all images of Calendar, Checkbox and Radiobutton folders. I try to manually set correct paths but it's overwritten by build action.

How can I fix it please ? Thanks in advance.

I use Xamarin.Forms v2.2.0.5-pre2 but not Toasts.Forms.Plugin (I saw during my search on google that the same issue can happen)

Answer (score 0):

**Cleaning** in Xamarin project was not enough. I had to delete **obj** and **bin** folders

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After doing this, the next build will show an error like: `Cannot get assembly name for "obj/iPhone/Release/MyApp.exe". Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`